# Reverse for 'signup_view' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/signup_view/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp AND build a Signup view BUT when i open browser then it shows me :-

> Reverse for 'signup_view' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/signup_view/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']

views.py

```
def signup_view(request,user_id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('mains:profile',user_id=user_id)
        else:
            form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
path('signup_view/<int:user_id>',views.signup_view, name='signup_view'),
```

login.html

```
<a href="{% url 'users:signup_view' user.id %}">Register Here.</a>
```

**Problem**

When i open browser then it is keep showing me `Reverse for 'signup_view' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/signup_view/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']`.

I don't know what am i missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: You can try changing your html link to {% url 'users:signup_view' request.user.id %}

Comment: It is not working. still showing that error

Comment: In that case it does seem like the answer you got from brandonris1 is the right one. You shouldn't be trying to get the user.id before the user has been created.

Comment: @Progam When you call  `form.save()`, it will return the created user instance, which will have an id, you can redirect using that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, You mean id instead of user_id. If i am not wrong, can you upload as an answer. Please

Comment: @Progam What you are asking for is a different question, It would be incorrect for me to add an answer! Just do this `user = form.save()` and in redirect `redirect('mains:profile',user_id=user.id)` or `user.pk` will also work

Comment: It is still not showing. Stiil showing the same error

Comment: @Progam brandonris1's answer is correct you have to do that, you cannot add any id / user_id in your url pattern for signup. But since you want to redirect when you save the form you get an instance of a user, which **now** has an id which you can use to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is reporting that you are trying to access your signup view without passing the user_id parameter to it which makes sense. Assuming that the purpose of your signup view is to actually have users create a user within your application, it stands to reason that there wouldn't be any user_id for that user when accessing the login view. Therefore, the user_id url parameter would not be passed when calling the view itself (since it doesn't yet exist).

That being said, I think it stands to reason that if you remove the user_id url parameter from both your view and your template, the page will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your precious Answer. It helped me a lot. BUT  Can i pass only `id` with it ?

Comment: The problem is that if you are a user who is trying to create a user instance, you won't ever have an id to pass.